# The authorisation bearer isn't read correctly server-side

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have started working on an old application developed in PHP with codeigniter. The previous dev isn't in the company anymore, I'm all alone to figure out what's happening.

First of all, the code seems to be working as intended on the first "development" server, but raises an error on the "test" server. The code is the same, the servers should be configured the same (I still don't have all the clearances I need to check this). Anyway, here is the logic :

There is a *login* page which asks the usual credentiels. They are sent to the back controler via POST, he then sends a request to the authentication API which returns a token if everything is correct.
The token is then written on the server, recovered in the front page and the user is redirected to the home page. This last redirection is completed with a "autorization: Bearer {token}" in the header.

Here are the screens, obtained via Postman :

First call from the front to Authentication::login :
[![first call from front to authenticaiton::login][1]][1]

The token is then correctly recovered, and apparently stored server-side :

**Authentication controler**

```
public function login(){
    [...]
    $make_call = $this->callAPI('POST', $this->config->items('apiurl') . 'token/', $data_array, ^this->config->items('apibearer'), $this->config->item('proxy'));
    $response = json_èdecode($make_call, true);
    if(isset($response['error'])){
        exit(json_encode(array('error'=>true, 'error_id'=>$response['error'])));
    }

    //parse token in JWT
    $token = $this->auc9_config->getParser()->parse((string) $response['id_token']);
    $token = $thi->writeToken($userId, $token);
    exit(json_encode(array('error' => false, 'token' => $tken->__toString())));
    }
}

public function writeToken($userId, $token){
    $role = $token->claims()->get('functional_post');
    $eds = $role['structure_element_id'];
    if(!is_null($eds)){
        $builder = $this->company_config->createBuilder();
        $new_token = $builder->issuedAt(new DateTimeImmutable())
            ->expriresAt((new DateTimeImmutable())->add(new DateInterval('PT' . (3600 * 4) . 'S')))
            ->withClaim('id_cr', $token->claims()->get('structure_id'))
            ->withClaim('eds', $eds)
            ->withClaim('uuid_tablet','web_demo')
            ->withClaim('version_apk', 'web_demo')
            ->getToken($this->company_config(getSigner(), $this->company_config->getSigningKey());
        return $new_token;
    } else {
        die(json_encode(array('error'=>true, 'error_id'=>'invalid_user')));
    }
}
```

JS side, the url is rewriten and the token is sent in the header :

**index.js**

```
if(data.token){
    const url = window.location.pathname.replace(/authentication\/?/, '');
    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url,
        headers: {
            'autorization': 'Bearer ' + data.token
        },
        success : function(data){
            window.location.reload();
        },
        error : function(err) {
            $(form).find('.erros').append('<p>invalid token</p>')
        }
    });
}
```

Finaly, the home page is called via the last ajax call, the the page is loaded if the token workds properly :

**Home controler**

```
public function index(){
    $home_page = $this->home_page->fetch_activated();
    if(home_page === null){
        show_404();
    }else{
        //display content
        [...]
    }
}
```

**Home Model**

```
class HomePage extends MY_Model {
    [...]
    public function fetch_activated() {
        $result = $this->read(array('active IS NOT NULL' => null, 'active >' => 0));
        return count($result) === 1 ? $result[0] : null;
    }
}
```

**Error : **
In the development server, the user is correctly redirected to the home page
In the test server, the user is rooted to the 404 page

Without ssh access to the server, I can't put up some exit() command via VIM and watch the results, nor can I access any log file.
Do you have any idea whats I can do ?

Edit1 : transform images to code

Edit2 : added Home Model

Comment: What does `fetch_activated` do and are it's dependencies (some sort of storage i assume) the same on both servers? This looks like the usual case of "missing record X on database Y" but, as already said by @AlonEitan there's little we can do to help you out, especially via images of code.

Comment: Sorry for the images, I rewrote the code instead.


The _fetch_active_ is a function seen in the model of the homePage. It apparently checks something in the database : 

`class HomePage extends MY_Model {`
`[...]`
`public function fetch_activated() {`
`$result = $this->read(array('active IS NOT NULL' => null, 'active >' => 0));`
`return count($result) === 1 ? $result[0] : null;`
`}`

Comment: There you go, it would seem you need a record on the table that `MY_Model` represents. A record with a positive integer in the `active` column. Compare the dataset between the environments/servers and create/edit the records as necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said by @nitrin0, there was a problem in the database. Once I got the credentials to access is, troubleshouting the problem was quite easy.